# How can I get the current connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, migration

**Given Scenratio:**

We've built a web application using Asp.net MVC and Entity Framework Code First, which builds a database dynamically for each customer.

Given a connection string (connectionStr) and a certain Configuration, We've made `Add Migrations [Name]` in order to create an empty migration, which has an empty `Up` function. We did that on purpose.

We don't wanna use automatic migrations here - we want full control, so we have a program making the migrations using a `DbMigrator` Class.

Our goal is to run a manual Seed inside this `Up` function.

This is some of the code incharge of making the migration, which indeed works perfectly:

```
Dim myConfiguration As New SomeNamespace.Migrations.Config1.Configuration
myConfiguration.TargetDatabase = New Infrastructure.DbConnectionInfo(connectionStr, "System.Data.SqlClient")

Dim dbMig As New Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(myConfiguration)
If dbMig.GetPendingMigrations.Count > 0 Then
  dbMig.Update() ' This makes the Up function work - the problem is inside it.
End If
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that when the `Up` function of the Migration is run, we cannot get the database context. We need it in order to make a Seed.

We hope that there's a way to get the Configuration object (**myConfiguration**) used to initiate the DbMigration (dbMig) instance, or some other way, so we can get the database context (maybe getting the ConnectionString somehow).

Help getting access to one of configuration object / database context / ConnectionString -  would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because what Up method does is filling `Operations` collection, and `DbMigrator` class actually executes these operations. So there is no 'context' when up is called.

What you can do is get connection string via `ConfigurationManager` class directly

Comment: But the Up method doesn't work in an empty space.. it works on a database to which I need the context. I didn't understand what do you mean exactly by using the ConfigurationManager directly. What i'm trying to do is initializing the migration class manually and passing it the context as a parameter from outside.

Comment: It doesn't work on database, it creates set of `MigrationStatement` object, then each of them goes to `MigrationSqlGenerator` class and the statements generated are executed against database. If you connection string name is constant you can get it by writing ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourName"].ConnectionString